# Recoger Bundle enviar un int y recibir null

Tags: android, activity

Se que es muy básico pero me esta volviendo loco. No entiendo por que en mi segunda activity recojo null.

Este es el código de la primera activty:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Listado.this,Repetir.class);
Log.i("LISTADO: ","ID:"+bc.getId());
i.putExtra("iden",bc.getId());
i.putExtra("usuario",bc.getUsuario());
i.putExtra("tipo",bc.getTipo());
startActivity(i);
```

y es el código de la segunda:

```
mP = new P();
Log.i("REPETIR: ","ID:"+getIntent().getStringExtra("iden"));
mP.setId(Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("iden")));
mP.setUsuario(getIntent().getStringExtra("usuario"));
mP.setTipo(getIntent().getStringExtra("tipo"));
```

Y esto lo que obtengo al depurar en los log:

> I/LISTADO:: ID:1
>
> I/REPETIR:: ID:null

y claro esta este error al parsear a int un null:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"

¿como puede ser que antes de enviar tenga valor 1 y reciba null?

gracias

Comment: El codigo es correcto, simplemente asegura recibir los valores especificados en las llaves "iden", "usuario", "tipo"

Comment: creo que es mejor utilizar el getInt que no hacer un casting ... qué opinas? por sabe de buenas prácticas de programación

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo he solucionado con:

```
 miPlan.setId(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id"));
```

Espero que le pueda servir a alguien

Comment: Si el problema era que no recibias este valor se debe simplemente a que no lo estabas enviando , en tu pregunta dice "iden" no "id".

Comment: si era un error también, pero creo que se debía también al tipo int del dato